# Development environment in Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I've recently started using Microsoft Azure and Visual Studio Team Services.
We use VS Team Services for cloud storage of our source repositories in TFS.
Continous deployment is configured to build and deploy on every commit.

As of now, our development environment is public and can be visited by anyone (published to azurewebsites.net)

However, we would like our development environment to be private and not accessible using a userfriendly url. We could implement some authorization on the web site to prevent others seeing our development site, but there must be another way.

There are ways to accomplish this using deployment slots in a staging area (will give me some guid url), but it doesn't seem right.

Is there any built in support to Azure (or Visual Studio Team Services) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage domain and / or IP address restrictions to limit who can connect into your host.  See: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/12/09/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/.

Comment: Thank you! Tried it out and it worked fine. Anyway, I think this feature (or another solution) should be present by default as a configuration option in Azure.

Comment: It is, depending on what the service type is you are using.  Cloud Services (Web/Worker Roles and Virtual Machines) have Access Controls Lists (ACLs) which you can use the achieve this.  SQL Azure Database has a "Firewall" which achieves the same thing.  This is just the way you need to achieve it for Websites :).  Have fun!

Comment: Great, thank you for your input. I'm still a rookie when it comes to Azure :-)